# Add index.routing.allocation.require.box_type tag to the old indexes?

Tags: elasticsearch

I try to use `hot/warm` architecture,but there are already a lot indexs.

Can i add the `index.routing.allocation.require.box_type` tag to the old index?

Answer (score 1):

you should set index settings using api methods. For all indices use `_all`.

Example:

```
curl -XPUT -d '{"index.routing.allocation.require.box_type": "warm"}' localhost:9200/_all/_settings?preserve_existing=true
```

Params `preserve_existing=true` means do not override existing `box_type`

Comment: Hi, it would be very nice of you to provide some context or explanation for the code you've given. Thanks!